# Upgrading Postgres.app 9.1 to 9.2, getting lc_collate values do not match error

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I'm upgrading a Postgres.app on my Macbook Pro (my development machine) and I'm getting an error when I run:

```
pg_upgrade -b /Users/foo/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/ 
           -B /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/ 
           -d /Users/foo/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var-9.1/ 
           -D /Users/foo/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var
```

The error I'm getting:

```
lc_collate cluster values do not match:  old "en_US", new "en_US.UTF-8"
```

**How do I correct this?**

Note: *I used to have [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) running 9.1, but I overwrote it. The directions I should have read/followed is: [Upgrading Postgres.app](http://nathany.com/upgrading-postgres/). So the old bin is gone, but I still have the data directory. Instead I downloaded Postgres 9.1 and installed it elsewhere to use the bin directory to upgrade and move my data to the new Postgres.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm migrating data and don't care about anything new in the database, I just deleted whatever was there (of course you can back it up to be safe):

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var
```

and created a new one with locale en_US, with the following:

```
initdb --locale=en_US -D ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var
```

Then I just ran the upgrade:

```
pg_upgrade -b ~/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/ 
           -B /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/ 
           -d ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var-9.1/ 
           -D ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var
```

Then just run the analyzer and all was good.

```
./analyze_new_cluster.sh
```

I connected with pgAdmin3 and all the data was as it should be.

Answer (score 3):

from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/pgupgrade.html

> Initialize the new PostgreSQL cluster
>
> Initialize the new cluster using initdb. Again, use compatible initdb
>   flags that match the old cluster. Many prebuilt installers do this
>   step automatically. There is no need to start the new cluster.

When you run initdb make sure --lc-collate=locale is the same as the old db e.g "en_us"

Comment: The DB I'm migrating from is set to a locale that apparently doesn't exist on my system, so using the --locale flag with initdb is impossible. Am I missing something or was this overlooked with initdb?